# Process a string in multiple substrings

Tags: python

I am not able to achieve an efficient algorithm that is able to do this operation.

I have an output from one of my process, that is formatted as following:

```
stringA*stringB-stringC-stringD....-stringN
```

I am trying to get stringA in one variable, and take stringB and stringC joined in another variable, while dumping the rest.

```
var1 contain stringA
var2 contain stringA-stringB
```

So far I am able to grab stringA using split:

```
cutstringA=longstring.split("*")[0]
```

But I can't find a way to grab stringB and stringC, without make 3 call to split:

```
tmpstr=longstring.split("*")[1] #return stringB-stringC.....-stringN
cutstringB=tmpstr.split("-")[0] #return stringB
cutstringC=tmpstr.split("-")[1] #return stringC
cutstringBC="{}-{}".format(cutstringB, cutstringC) #return stringB-stringC
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this? Or the only way is to break multiple times the big string, and then join together the pieces that I want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to keep splitting for a single element, you can split once on "*" the get the first element then split the remaining string on "-" and join the first two of the remaining elements:

```
s = "stringA*stringB-stringC-stringD"

spl =  s.split("*",1)
a, b  = spl[0],"-".join(spl[1].split("-",2)[0:2])
print(a,b)
stringA stringB-stringC
```

Or `str.translate` to remove both characters and split once and join:

```
s = "stringA*stringB-stringC-stringD"
tbl = str.maketrans("*-","  ")
spl = s.translate(tbl).split()
a,b  = spl[0],"-".join(spl[1:3])
print(a,b)

stringA stringB-stringC
```

Splitting will be the most efficient.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is what I prefer, compared to the regex :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could split your string into two is by using `regex`:

```
import re

s = "stringA*stringB-stringC-stringD-stringE"
m = re.match("(\\w+)\\*(\\w+\\-\\w+)\\b", s)
v1 = m.group(1)
v2 = m.group(2)
```

After matching we put each result into it's own var, resulting in:

```
('stringA', 'stringB-stringC')
```